# Discord.py Get all roles from mentioned member

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

is there a way to send all of the mentioned person's roles to a channel?

Start of my code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("Enhanced Permissions")
async def softban(ctx, user : discord.Member,
```

Not sure what to do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
roles = user.roles
roles = [role.name for role in roles]
await ctx.send(f"```{','.join(roles)}```"
````

This will fetch the roles belonging to `user` and print them within codeblocks.

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role.mention

`role.mention` is preferred (better formatting) but careful that will cause a ping to the people who have that role (given the role is `mentionable`)  
When using `role.mention` in an [`embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#embed) it will not cause a ping.

Comment: @TinNguyen Using mention without enclosing the output in embed / codeblocks tends to ping the default role/ everyone. That's why I decided to opt for this. But otherwise yeah, you're correct.